# Mobile Push Sharing the same app in multiple business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

We currently have Mobile Push set up for a client in a certain way, and want to move to another setup. I'm looking for validation, on whether a certain mobile push setup is possible.

Mobile app: There is one app used globally.

The current situation: We have a parent BU (global) and below that we have some child BUs. Currently, mobile push is implemented at the parent level only.

The new situation: We will create a middle layer in BU structure/hierarchy, so that we have:
* a parent BU 
-> Region BU (e.g. Europe) 
---> Market BU (countries).

Ideally, I want to have Mobile Push implemented on the **region** level. The way I would like to accomplish this, is to delay the registration of the contactKey to only happen after the first login -> because then we know what region someone should be sent to.

- One person should only belong to one region and this will not change after initial registration.
- We also want to stop using mobile push in the Parent BU whilst making this switch.

So there are actually 2 main questions:

1. Is this setup technically possible, to register the same app in multiple BU's and then divide the contacts over the right BU's like mentioned above?
2. If it is indeed the right way to do things, we would need to migrate the existing contacts from the Parent BU to the new Regional level. I've found this link in another thread, is this the correct way to accomplish this migration? https://gist.github.com/sfmc-mobilepushsdk/f7e04c905bd97656496b1bc0a8ec7c30

Answer (score 0):

You can move an app between business units, but you can not share an app between business units.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but not sure if I fully understand it: I want to integrate one mobile app into 2 business units. Then, I want to register 'user A' in BU 1 and 'user B' in BU 2. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, just test it.

Comment: Hi Bill, how can you move an app to a different BU?

Comment: Init the SDK with the correct values provided in your application's administration page from the UI.

Comment: Yeah okay sorry I thought you meant you can move the app inside of SFMC from one BU to another keeping the App ID and key intact.